# Order by chronological date instead of menu order

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code to show thumbnails of all child pages, this is code i found online and customised to my client site.

I am trying to customise it to be order by most recent page down to the oldest instead of by menu order, but when i replace menu_order with date it just shows nothing?

Any idea how i can do this? Many thanks

```
    <?php
    $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
    $i = 0;
    if ( $child_pages ) :
    foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChilds ) :
        $gchild_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$pageChilds->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
        if($gchild_pages) :
        foreach ($gchild_pages as $pageChild):
        setup_postdata( $pageChild );
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'work-thumb');
        if($thumbnail == "") continue; // Skip pages without a thumbnail

    ?>

       <div class="child-thumb">
        <p><a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark"><?= $thumbnail ?></a></p>
       <h3><a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?= $pageChild->post_title ?>"><?= $pageChild->post_title ?></a></h3>
       </div>
    </a>
<?

    endforeach;
    endif;
endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Are you using like `ORDER BY date` ? If so it wont work since date is a mysql keyword and you have to use like  ORDER BY \`date\`

Comment: Yes that's how i was using it. If i do ORDER BY `date`will it order from most recent to oldest? thanks

Comment: no date is a mysql function.. If your column name matches mysql functions you should escape it with back ticks like this \`date\` instead of just date

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY `date`", 'OBJECT');
```